# Could not remove unicode character

Tags: oracle, unicode, encoding, hex

I have a text string in Oracle table ("NGUYỄN NGỌC HOÀNG"). I have tried to replace the Unicode string (my expected result is "NGUYEN NGOC HOANG") but it didn't work.

Then I tried to convert it to HEX as below: `select rawtohex(UnicodeColumn) from TestTable`;
Here is the result: `4E 47 55 59 C3 8A CC 83 4E 20 4E 47 4F CC A3 43 20 48 4F 41 CC 80 4E 47`

Following the Unicode table: The corresponding characters are: `NGUYÃŠÌƒN NGOÌ£C HOAÌ€NG`

Could anyone help me this case (Oracle script), I don't have experience about the encoding.

> Update 1:

I have tried the solution from Barbaros Özhan but it didn't work

> SQL> with tab as ( select '&i_str1' str1 from dual )   2  select str1,
>   utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(str1,'nls_sort=binary_ai'))) str2
>   from tab SQL> / Enter value for i_str1: NGUYỄN NGỌC HOÀNG

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL> with tab as ( select '&i_str1' str1 from dual )
  2  select str1, utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(str1,'nls_sort=binary_ai'))) str2 from tab
SQL> /
Enter value for i_str1: NGUYỄN NGỌC HOÀNG
```

and you get the desired result.

Comment: I have tried but it didn't work. Could you take a look at my Updated question?

Comment: Hi Sir, Can I keep the Uppercase?

Comment: @HoangTran i can not test in my db whether works but could you replace str2 with it `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(rawtohex(str1))` in your db.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java for connecting to Oracle DBMS, try the Java code below to convert to unaccent character, after that update the row in DBMS.

```
public static String unAccent(String s) {
    String temp = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
    return pattern.matcher(temp).replaceAll("").replaceAll("Đ", "D").replace("đ", "");
}
```

Comment: Thank, but is there any way to do it by the script?

Comment: What script that you mean? Oracle script or something else?

Comment: Oracle script, I want to process it in the database only

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function to convert to non-accent character:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_CONVERT_TO_VN
(
    STRINPUT IN NVARCHAR2
)
RETURN NVARCHAR2
IS
    STRCONVERT NVARCHAR2(32527);
BEGIN
STRCONVERT := TRANSLATE(
    STRINPUT, 'áàảãạăắằẳẵặâấầẩẫậđéèẻẽẹêếềểễệíìỉĩịóòỏõọôốồổỗộơớờởỡợúùủũụưứừửữựýỳỷỹỵÁÀẢÃẠĂẮẰẲẴẶÂẤẦẨẪẬĐÉÈẺẼẸÊẾỀỂỄỆÍÌỈĨỊÓÒỎÕỌÔỐỒỔỖỘƠỚỜỞỠỢÚÙỦŨỤƯỨỪỬỮỰÝỲỶỸỴ', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadeeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiooooooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuyyyyyAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADEEEEEEEEEEEIIIIIOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOUUUUUUUUUUUYYYYY'
);
RETURN STRCONVERT;
END;
```